# onclick method does not exist error?

Tags: java, android

this is the description of the error

There should be no spaces in the onClick handler name  The onClick attribute value should be the name of a method in this View's context to invoke when the view is clicked. This name must correspond to a public method that takes exactly one parameter of type View.  Must be a string value, using '\;' to escape characters such as '\n' or '\uxxxx' for a unicode character.

```
btnClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
txtBox1 = (EditText) findViewById(editText9);
txtBox2 = (EditText) findViewById(editText10);



btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String input1 = txtBox1.getText().toString();
        byte[] bytes = input1.getBytes();
        final StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : bytes) {
            int val = b;
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                binary.append((val & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1);
                val <<= 1;
            }
            binary.append(' ');
            txtBox2.setText(binary);
        }

btnClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

        btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)              
getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                String text = txtBox2.getText().toString();
                ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("text", text);
                clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Text Copied",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }


        });


        txtBox2 = (EditText) findViewById(editText10);
        txtBox1 = (EditText) findViewById(editText9);
        btnClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);

        btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){

                txtBox2.setText("");
                txtBox1.setText("");
            }
        });

        btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){

                txtBox2.setText("");
                String s = new String(binary);
                txtBox1.setText(s);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Show us the complete stacktrace.

Comment: One odd thing.  At the end you are calling `btnClick.setOnClickListener` twice on the same `Button`.

Comment: The problem is coming from one of your layout XML files, not the Java code. You have an `android:onClick` attribute on something, and the value you have for it can't be found as a valid method in the `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

you have used same name `btnClick` for different  3 Button. may be this is the problem. use different name.

Answer (score 0):

You have not closed the OnClickListener interface.
Change

```
btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String input1 = txtBox1.getText().toString();
        byte[] bytes = input1.getBytes();
        final StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : bytes) {
            int val = b;
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                binary.append((val & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1);
                val <<= 1;
            }
            binary.append(' ');
            txtBox2.setText(binary);
        }
```

to

```
btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String input1 = txtBox1.getText().toString();
        byte[] bytes = input1.getBytes();
        final StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : bytes) {
            int val = b;
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                binary.append((val & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1);
                val <<= 1;
            }
            binary.append(' ');
            txtBox2.setText(binary);
        }
}
});
```

Note that I have added

}
    });
 to your code. After this line start your next code.

Comment: I have done that but the error persists thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Just use `different Button variables` for different button `ids` in your `xml`, don't use same button name to call `onClick` methods.
For example:

```
Button btnClick,btnClick1,btnClick2;
```

For more information please visit this [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38323988/multiple-onclicklistener-for-one-button)

Comment: i have tried that but the same error still persists...thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to create different buttons variables names and ids

**For Example**

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mContext = this;
    mActivity = this;

    btnClick1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnClick2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btnClick3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    btnClick4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    txtBox1 = (EditText) findViewById(editText9);
    txtBox2 = (EditText) findViewById(editText10);


    btnClick1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String input1 = txtBox1.getText().toString();
                byte[] bytes = input1.getBytes();
                final StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();
                for (byte b : bytes) {
                    int val = b;
                    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                        binary.append((val & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1);
                        val <<= 1;
                    }
                    binary.append(' ');
                    txtBox2.setText(binary);
                }
            }
        });
        btnClick2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)
                        getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                String text = txtBox2.getText().toString();
                ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("text", text);
                clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Text Copied",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
        btnClick3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txtBox2.setText("");
                txtBox1.setText("");
            }
        });
        btnClick4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txtBox2.setText("");
                String s = new String(binary);
                txtBox1.setText(s);
            }
        });
}
```

Check this

Comment: Hello there i have tried thiis but the same error still persists...Thanks for helping