# How to detect the button click in Activity from the Alert Dialog present in a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I am having a DialogFragment like this,

```
public class Dfragment extends DialogFragment {

    public Dfragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        ab.setMessage("Delete Everything").setTitle("DELETE DB")
                .setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    }
                })

                .setNegativeButton("CANCEL",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()

                { @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {         }
                });


        return ab.create();
    }

}
```

I can detect the positive/negative from within the Fragment, but how do I detect it from an Activity from where it had been called.

Here is the code implemented in the Activity,

```
 Dfragment frag = new Dfragment();
        frag.show(getFragmentManager(),"THISDIALOG");
```

So in the Activity how do I determine which button has been clicked ?

Things I tried so far,

From the above Fragment code,

setPositiveButton("OK",null) replaced in the above code but still did not work.

What code will I need to modify to make it work as desired ?

**EDIT 1**:

I know it can be achieved by interfaces but I would like to do it without that.

Comment: as usual 1. get activity, 2. cast to the interface 3. call the method from interface and pass which button was clicked ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Communicating between a fragment and an activity - best practices.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247954/communicating-between-a-fragment-and-an-activity-best-practices)

Comment: @Selvin Edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have one suggetion for you. You can do like:

```
public abstract class Dfragment extends DialogFragment {

    public Dfragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        ab.setMessage("Delete Everything").setTitle("DELETE DB")
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        onPositiveButtonClick();
                    }
                })

                .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()

                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        onNegativeButtonClick();
                    }

                });


        return ab.create();
    }

    public abstract void onPositiveButtonClick();

    public abstract void onNegativeButtonClick();

}
```

And Create object

```
Dfragment frag = new Dfragment() {
    @Override
    public void onPositiveButtonClick() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNegativeButtonClick() {

    }
};
frag.show(getFragmentManager(),"THISDIALOG");
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to detect it from activity.
Just write whatever your code is in that listeners and do call the same way you are calling. for example..

```
  @Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    ab.setMessage("Delete Everything").setTitle("DELETE DB")
            .setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   Log.d("log", "this will log anyway");
                }
            })

            .setNegativeButton("CANCEL",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()

            { @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {         }
            });


    return ab.create();
}
```

apart from this if you want to do any thing else than you need to implement a `callback`

good luck

Comment: Dude common, don't I know that. My question was how to detect it from main activity ?

Answer (score 0):

Use interface for this,

```
public class Dfragment extends DialogFragment {

Clicks objclick;

public Dfragment() {
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    ab.setMessage("Delete Everything").setTitle("DELETE DB")
            .setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                     obj.onclick();
                }
            })

            .setNegativeButton("CANCEL",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()

            { @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {         }
            });


    return ab.create();
}

public void clicklistner(Clicks click){
    objclick=click;
}


  }
```

make an interface,

```
public interface Clicks{
    public void onclick();
}
```

call clicklistner method from your activity,

```
frag.clicklistner(new....
```

Comment: Please read my question carefully. I do not want to use an interface.