# How can I pass an object to a widget

Tags: java, android, android-studio, widget, home-screen-widget

I am currently making an app that containing a widget.
When placing the app **a WidgetConfigure Activity** opens where you can select an object out of a recycleViewer.

The object (Kitten) implements the **parcelable** and the recyleviewer is filled by an adapter class.

When the eventListner of that recyleviewer is triggered, the selected object must be passed to the widget since I need properties from that object in my widget.

I'm currently completely stuck and confused how I can pass an object to the widget. 
**How can I pass an object to the widget?**

Here is my code that will run in the eventListner in 
`LongEventConfigureActivity`:

```
private void makeWidget(Event myObj){

    // How I normally passing data to an activity/fragment

    //Intent i = new Intent();
    //Bundle b = new Bundle();
    //b.putParcelable(CONST_PARCELKEY, myObj);
    //i.putExtras(b);
    //i.setClass(this, ObjectDetailActivity.class);
    //startActivity(i);

    // Example of how to pass data to the widget
    final Context context = LongEventWidgetConfigureActivity.this;

    // When the button is clicked, store the string locally
    String widgetText = txtWidgetText.getText().toString();
    saveTitlePref(context, mAppWidgetId, widgetText);

    // It is the responsibility of the configuration activity to update the app widget
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    LongEventWidget.updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, mAppWidgetId);

    // Make sure we pass back the original appWidgetId
    Intent resultValue = new Intent();
    resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
    finish();

}


@Override
public void onItemClick(Event e) {
    makeWidget(e);
}
```

Also I need to find a way when the user tapping this widget, a certain activity of my app will open that will receive that object.

[Summery of the problem (I don't have the privilege to post an image yet)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMKC0.png)

Comment: You can implement the class with Serializable . In that way your object can pass through Intent.

Comment: The problem is that the intent for a widget is a bit different than a regular activity. 

Normally I pass objects using parceable in a similar manner:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42266436/passing-objects-between-fragments 


This is how an intent looks like for a widget:

Intent intent = new Intent(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE, null, this, ChecksWidgetProvider.class);
intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, new int[] {mAppWidgetId});
sendBroadcast(intent);

But I'm confused since it NEED id's, I don't know how to pass an object or a list to it.