# How to read checkbox isChecked from another fragment?

Tags: android, checkbox, fragment

I just added a new blank fragment to my App and added 12 Checkboxes inside it.
Now I need to read the isChecked property from another fragment.
How I can do that.

I tried this but I get NullPointer exception when I try to use the variable.

```
View FiltersView = FilterEvents.newInstance().getView();//FilterEvents is another fragment

CheckBox F1_1 = FiltersView.findViewById(R.id.filter1_1);
CheckBox F1_2 = FiltersView.findViewById(R.id.filter1_2);
CheckBox F1_3 = FiltersView.findViewById(R.id.filter1_3);
CheckBox F1_4 = FiltersView.findViewById(R.id.filter1_4);
CheckBox F1_5 = FiltersView.findViewById(R.id.filter1_5);
CheckBox F1_6 = FiltersView.findViewById(R.id.filter1_6);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing objects between fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42266436/passing-objects-between-fragments)

Comment: You can use an  interface or something like  EventBus 


  [1]: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html
  [2]: https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: You can use ViewModel objects to share data between fragments. ViewModel would be linked to activity that owns fragments

Comment: ViewModel or with the supportFragmentManager(accessible by getActivity() in Fragment), you can get the list of All Fragments and then find and get a reference of the Fragment where the CheckBox is and then call Fragment.getView()

Comment: Also, there is not guarantee that the Fragment View will be ready when you call getView() this way just after newInstance()