# Android : How to efficiently send and receive data between Fragment and Activity?

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm using two fragments in my activity using `ViewPager` and `TabLayout`. I want to send and receive data between my `Activity` and my `Fragments`.

I don't prefer to use a class with `static` variables to fix this problem. Is there a better way to do this task with out loosing much memory and resources. Because static data members never die in the whole life cycle of app. So they never release any chunk of memory. Which is a big problem for app to run in Samsung devices or you can say non rooted devices who restrict the usage of **RAM**.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247954/communicating-between-a-fragment-and-an-activity-best-practices#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Interface. Here is an excerpt from Android doc which contains details with examples of how to communicate between `Fragment` and `Activity` and vice versa:  [Define an Interface](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#DefineInterface).

> To allow a Fragment to communicate up to its Activity, you can define an interface in the Fragment class and implement it within the Activity. The Fragment captures the interface implementation during its onAttach() lifecycle method and can then call the Interface methods in order to communicate with the Activity.

This makes your `Fragment` modular and allows you to reuse the same `Fragment` in multiple activities. All you would need to do is implement the `interface` in the new `Activity`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in 2 ways. 
First method is define a interface. [interface example](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Creating-Custom-Listeners)
Second method is eventbus. [eventbus library](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

My preference eventbus. Even if possible, learn rxjava and do it with the event logic there. [Rxjava tutorial](https://blog.mindorks.com/implementing-eventbus-with-rxjava-rxbus-e6c940a94bd8)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of Fragment to Activity communication:

public class HeadlinesFragment extends ListFragment {
    OnHeadlineSelectedListener mCallback;

```
// Container Activity must implement this interface
public interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
    public void onArticleSelected(int position);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
    try {
        mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
    }
}
```

}