# How to pass data from a searchview that is in mainAcitivy, to a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, searchview

How to pass data from a searchview that is in mainActivity, to a fragment? I'm sweating a BottonNavigationActivity.

Already tried:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("teste", "123");
                fragment2.setArguments(bundle);

            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    return true;
}
```

in Fragment:

```
 Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();

    if (bundle != null) {
        String foo = getArguments().getString("teste");

        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), foo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

and too:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
if (bundle != null) {
        String foo = bundle.getString("teste");

        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), foo, 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

And the app to work. can anybody help me?

adding fragment:

```
Fragment currentFragment;
private home fragment1 = new home();
private clientes fragment2 = new clientes();
private contas_pagar fragment3 = new contas_pagar();

private BottomViewPagerAdapter bottomViewPagerAdapter;
private ArrayList<AHBottomNavigationItem> bottomNavigationItems = new ArrayList<>();

// UI
private AHBottomNavigationViewPager viewPagerBottom;
private AHBottomNavigation bottomNavigation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initUI();
}

private void initUI() {

    bottomNavigation = (AHBottomNavigation) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    viewPagerBottom = (AHBottomNavigationViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager_bottom);

    //Aqui onde é adicionado os fragments no bottom
    viewPagerBottom.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
    bottomViewPagerAdapter = new BottomViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    bottomViewPagerAdapter.add(fragment1);
    bottomViewPagerAdapter.add(fragment2);
    bottomViewPagerAdapter.add(fragment3);
    viewPagerBottom.setAdapter(bottomViewPagerAdapter);

    currentFragment = bottomViewPagerAdapter.getCurrentFragment();


    AHBottomNavigationItem item1 = new AHBottomNavigationItem("Home", R.drawable.ic_home_black_24dp);
    AHBottomNavigationItem item2 = new AHBottomNavigationItem("Clientes", R.drawable.clientes);
    AHBottomNavigationItem item3 = new AHBottomNavigationItem("Contas", R.drawable.pagar);;

    bottomNavigationItems.add(item1);
    bottomNavigationItems.add(item2);
    bottomNavigationItems.add(item3);


    bottomNavigation.addItems(bottomNavigationItems);


    bottomNavigation.setAccentColor(Color.parseColor("#F63D2B"));
    bottomNavigation.setInactiveColor(Color.parseColor("#747474"));
    bottomNavigation.setCurrentItem(0);

    //bottomNavigation.setNotification("Vencida", 2);

    bottomNavigation.findViewById(R.id.textView18);


    bottomNavigation.setOnTabSelectedListener(new AHBottomNavigation.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTabSelected(int position, boolean wasSelected) {

            if (currentFragment == null) {
                currentFragment = bottomViewPagerAdapter.getCurrentFragment();
            }


            if (currentFragment != null) {
                if (currentFragment instanceof home) {

                    fragment1.willBeHidden();

                } else if (currentFragment instanceof clientes) {

                    fragment2.willBeHidden();

                } else if (currentFragment instanceof contas_pagar) {

                    fragment3.willBeHidden();

                }
            }

            //Aqui é onde é setado qual o fragment atual
            //Em seguida é pego o fragment atual e feito o fade dependendo de qual instancia for
            viewPagerBottom.setCurrentItem(position, false);
            currentFragment = bottomViewPagerAdapter.getCurrentFragment();

            if (currentFragment instanceof home) {

                fragment1.willBeDisplayed();

            } else if (currentFragment instanceof clientes) {

                fragment2.willBeDisplayed();

            } else if (currentFragment instanceof contas_pagar) {

                fragment3.willBeDisplayed();

            }

            if (position == 0) {

            }

            return true;
        }
    });

    bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationPositionListener(new AHBottomNavigation.OnNavigationPositionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPositionChange(int y) {
            Log.d("DemoActivity", "BottomNavigation Position: " + y);
        }
    });
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class BottomViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
private Fragment currentFragment;

public BottomViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

public void add(Fragment frag) {
    this.fragments.add(frag);

}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return fragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragments.size();
}

@Override
public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) 
{
    if (getCurrentFragment() != object) {
        currentFragment = ((Fragment) object);
    }
    super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);
}

/**
 * Get the current fragment
 */
public Fragment getCurrentFragment() {
    return currentFragment;
}
}
```

Logcat:

> 02-14 13:50:07.435 12250-12250/insidetechnology.studio.ostdor.forbusiness E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                             Process: insidetechnology.studio.ostdor.forbusiness, PID: 12250
>                                                                                             java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already active
>                                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setArguments(Fragment.java:562)
>                                                                                                  at insidetechnology.studio.ostdor.forbusiness.MainActivity$2.onQueryTextSubmit(MainActivity.java:196)
>                                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.onSubmitQuery(SearchView.java:1242)
>                                                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$9.onEditorAction(SearchView.java:1219)
>                                                                                                 at android.widget.TextView.onEditorAction(TextView.java:4983)
>                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.performEditorAction(EditableInputConnection.java:145)
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:364)
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:91)
>                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
>                                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:208)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6267)
>                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)

Comment: Is the fragment already visible?

Comment: Yes, I added the other way I tried to get the data too, and nothing works

Comment: You can use interfaces or and event bus to communicate between fragment and activity. Just Google how to communicate between activity and fragment.

Comment: @karandeepsingh And how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setArguments()` function is used to pass data for the creation of Fragments. To communicate with existing Fragments, you would just call a method of your custom Fragment class itself:

```
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    if (fragment2 instanceof clientes) { 
        ((clientes)fragment2).setTestString("123");
    }
}
```

You need to add a method `setTestString` to your `fragment2` like this:

```
public void setTestString(String text) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), foo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

There's actually a good article in [Google's Android Training](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#Deliver) that also describes how to pass data back to the Activity.

Comment: No fragment was created public void setTestString(String testString) {
        teste = testString;
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), teste, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

Comment: well it depends of the `findFragmentById()` can find a fragment with that id. If you added it by code you might to use `findFragmentByTag()`. Don't forget to add it with a Tag (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add(int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: I tried and nothing happened, it seems that it is always null, I put it without checking if it was or not null and the app stopped work

Comment: In code, I'm using one BottonNavigationActivity, the default Android Studio template.

Comment: You might need to use `getFragmentManager()` instead. You're using a Fragment(State)PagerAdapter subclass?

Comment: Yes, I'm using it, and where I put it getFragmentManager()?

Comment: can you post your code where you are adding your fragment?

Comment: @karandeepsingh yes, wait one minute

Comment: can you use `getCurrentFragment()` using your adapter, typecast it to your `fragment2` and call the public method where you want to pass the string?

Comment: yeah @karandeepsingh that's what I would do!

Comment: @karandeepsingh yes, ty guy

Answer (score 0):

You can communicate between activity and fragment by creating an interface callback. Invoke that callback in onQueryTextSubmit and recieve that value in fragment.

Comment: I can only pass this if the method is static, and after getting the string I need to call another method, being this not static, how would I call that other within that static? Or would it be possible to pass without being static?

Comment: I try :  public static void setTestString(Context context, String string) {
        String teste;
        teste = string;
        new clientes().buscarCliente();
        Toast.makeText(context, teste, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

Comment: No , there is no need to be static. further u can visit this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39309737/7399038

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getCurrentFragment()` using your adapter, typecast it to your fragment2 and call the public method where you want to pass the string.