# Get Edit text by id from fragment to its hosting Activity

Tags: android

I have one activity which is hosting several tabs(Fragment), now I want to get EditText by id from tab(Fragment) to its hosting activity and set listener on it.

So please help me to get rid of it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: why not set listener in `Fragment`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Communicating between a fragment and an activity - best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247954/communicating-between-a-fragment-and-an-activity-best-practices)

Comment: You can not use `findViewById()` which does not exists in same component .  You can communicate between Fragment and Activity.

Comment: `EditText edittext =fragmentview.findViewById(R.id.edittext);` and  set listener in Fragment

Answer (score 0):

To  find view by id from fragment, add this:

```
EditText edittext = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.edittext);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is

```
EditText editText = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.viewid);
if( editText != null){
  // set listener here 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity

```
public EditText editText;
if(editText != null)
editText.setOnClickListner(this);
```

In your Fragment

```
Activity activity = (Activity)context;
//where context is your fragment's context
activity.edtText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.viewid);
```

Make sure you set listener when editText is not null otherwise you will get null pointer exeption.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple solutions to this. In my opinion the best way is to make an interface named Callback as below

```
public interface Callback
{
public void onListenerActionPerformed(Some args);
}
```

Now in whatever fragment you want the listener to be attached, write a function

```
private Callback callback;
public void setCallback(Callback callback)
{
this.callback=callback;
}
```

Now register the listener on your EditText in the fragment and inside the body of the corresponding function write

```
callback.onListenerActionPerformed(Some parameter)
```

Now from your activity, right below where you have instantiated the fragment write,

```
 fragmentInstanceName.setCallback(new Callback(){
    public void onListenerActionPerformed(Some args){
    //Your implementation
    }  
    });
```