# How to use ImageViews from fragment in my mainactivity

Tags: java, android, html, android-fragments

So i have a SettingsActivity/layout with ImageViews, and can upload images from my phone gallery to these ImageViews which also then upload to firebase. There are currently 3 edit views and everything works fine until i wanted to try the following:

Now i wanted to have the ability to increase the amount of ImageViews upon certain criteria being met. For this i decided to move the ImageViews from this activity to a fragment activity and I created another activity with double the ImageViews. All the code for the upload/download of these ImageViews happen in the SettingsActivity. What's the best way to go about this? I've tried moving all the code over to the fragment activity but I end up with too much issues. What's the best way to go about using these imagesviews in the fragments(I have onclick listeners and other stuff that need the imageviews) in the SettingsActivity:

SettingsActivity.Java

```
    public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private ImageView mImage1, mImage2, mImage3;
        private String image1Url, image2Url, image3Url;

        public static FragmentManager fragmentManager;

        final int MaxTags = 5;
        private int MaxImages = 3;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            if(findViewById(R.id.profileImageContainer) != null){
                if(savedInstanceState!=null)
                    return;
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                SettingsDefault settingsDefault = new SettingsDefault();
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.profileImageContainer, settingsDefault, null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }

    getUserInfo();

            mImage1 = findViewById(R.id.image1);
            mImage2 = findViewById(R.id.image2);
            mImage3 = findViewById(R.id.image3);

            mUserDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userId);

            mImage1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                }
            });
            mImage2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
                }
            });
            mImage3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 3);
                }
            });

        ArrayAdapter<String> values;
        private void getUserInfo() {

            mUserDb.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if(dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()>0){


                        Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                        if(map.get("phone") != null){
                            phone = map.get("phone").toString();
                            mPhoneField.setText(phone);
                        }
                        if(map.get("sex") != null){
                            userSex = map.get("sex").toString();
                        }

                        Glide.clear(mImage1);
                        if(map.get("image1Url") != null){
                            image1Url = map.get("image1Url").toString();
                            switch(image1Url){
                                case "default":
                                    mImage1.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

                                    break;
                                default:
                                    Glide.with(getApplication()).load(image1Url).into(mImage1);
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        if(map.get("image2Url") != null){
                            image2Url = map.get("image2Url").toString();
                            switch(image2Url){
                                case "default":
                                    mImage2.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

                                    break;
                                default:
                                    Glide.with(getApplication()).load(image2Url).into(mImage2);
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        if(map.get("image3Url") != null){
                            image3Url = map.get("image3Url").toString();
                            switch(image3Url){
                                case "default":
                                    mImage3.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                break;
                                default:
                                    Glide.with(getApplication()).load(image3Url).into(mImage3);
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }




        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                final Uri resultUri = imageUri;
                if(resultUri != null){
                    final StorageReference filePath = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("profileImages").child(userId).child("image1");
                    Bitmap bitmap = null;

                    try {
                        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplication().getContentResolver(), resultUri);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, baos);
                    byte[] databytes = baos.toByteArray();
                    UploadTask uploadTask = filePath.putBytes(databytes);
                    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Upload Failed! Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                            toast.show();
                        }
                    });
                    uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            filePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                    Map newImage = new HashMap();
                                    newImage.put("image1Url", uri.toString());
                                    mUserDb.updateChildren(newImage);
                                    mImage1.setImageURI(resultUri);
                                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Upload Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                                    toast.show();
                                }
                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Upload Failed! Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                                    toast.show();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });

                }else{
                    finish();
                }

            }
            if(requestCode == 2 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                final Uri resultUri = imageUri;
                if(resultUri != null){
                    final StorageReference filePath = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("profileImages").child(userId).child("image2");
                    Bitmap bitmap = null;

                    try {
                        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplication().getContentResolver(), resultUri);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, baos);
                    byte[] databytes = baos.toByteArray();
                    UploadTask uploadTask = filePath.putBytes(databytes);
                    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Upload Failed! Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                            toast.show();
                        }
                    });
                    uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            filePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                    Map newImage = new HashMap();
                                    newImage.put("image2Url", uri.toString());
                                    mUserDb.updateChildren(newImage);
                                    mImage2.setImageURI(resultUri);
                                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Upload Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                                    toast.show();
                                }
                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Upload Failed! Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                                    toast.show();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });

                }else{
                    finish();
                }
            }
            if(requestCode == 3 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                final Uri resultUri = imageUri;
                if(resultUri != null){
                    final StorageReference filePath = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("profileImages").child(userId).child("image3");
                    Bitmap bitmap = null;

                    try {
                        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplication().getContentResolver(), resultUri);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, baos);
                    byte[] databytes = baos.toByteArray();
                    UploadTask uploadTask = filePath.putBytes(databytes);
                    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Upload Failed! Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                            toast.show();
                        }
                    });
                    uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            filePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                    Map newImage = new HashMap();
                                    newImage.put("image3Url", uri.toString());
                                    mUserDb.updateChildren(newImage);
                                    mImage3.setImageURI(resultUri);
                                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Upload Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                                    toast.show();
                                }
                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Upload Failed! Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                                    toast.show();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });

                }else{
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

SettingsDefault.Java (Fragment)

```
public class SettingsDefault extends Fragment {

    ImageView mImageView1;
    ImageView mImageView2;
    ImageView mImageView3;

    public SettingsDefault() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings_default, container, false);
        mImageView1 = view.findViewById(R.id.image1);
        mImageView2 = view.findViewById(R.id.image2);
        mImageView3 = view.findViewById(R.id.image3);
        return view;
    }

    public ImageView getImageView1(){
        return  mImageView1;
    }
    public ImageView getImageView2(){
        return  mImageView2;
    }
    public ImageView getImageView3(){
        return  mImageView3;
    }
```

Fragment's Layout(Moved the ImageViews from SettingsActivity to here)

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".Fragments.ProfileImages.SettingsUpgade1">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
        android:weightSum="3">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/image1"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_margin="20sp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/image2"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_margin="20sp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"

            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/image3"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_margin="20sp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/image4"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_margin="20sp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/image5"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_margin="20sp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"

            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/image6"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_margin="20sp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy!! Just use interface between your activity and fragment!! Like this link below!!

[Communicating between a fragment and an activity - best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14247954/11015369)

Comment: @ Ricardinho Thanks

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the info. Had a look at using interfaces which seems useful with simply tasks, but with so much going on in the activity with the imageviews it became really confusing and difficult to understand how to incorporate the interfaces to work with this app. So to simplify my life, I successfully managed to move all of the methods that utilize the ImageViews over to the fragment activity. Now i will do the same for the other fragment(only difference is it has double the imageviews), and will use a bolean or something to flick between the fragments. Not sure if this is the best way, specifically performance wise, but i ran the app and it seemed okay.