# By clicking button in main activity, i need to enable button of fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two buttons in different activity. By clicking "Button A" I need to enable "Button B"
"Button A" is in MainActivity.java and "Button B" is in QuestionFragment2018.java

```
        <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click me"
        android:id="@+id/clickButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="buttonClicked"/>
```

need to enable this fragment button

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnviewexplanation"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Inset"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/testbutton"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="Solution" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
    public void buttonClicked (View view){
}

QuestionFragment2018.java

    Button buttonExplanation = (Button) 
   rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnviewexplanation);
    buttonExplanation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            questionWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/" + 
   currentQuestion2018.getExplanationText());

        }
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Communicating between a fragment and an activity - best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247954/communicating-between-a-fragment-and-an-activity-best-practices)

Answer (score 0):

Most easy way to do this

in your mainActivity class Create a reference for your  fragment using fragment id in .xml

```
QuestionFragment2018 QuestionFragment2018=
    (QuestionFragment2018) 
  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.yourfragmentig)
```

create a function in QuestionFragment2018 doWorke() call this function from activity

```
QuestionFragment2018.doWorke()
```

Comment: Well it is a solution, but not a proper one, of course it may solve the problem, but it is hard to scale to next levels. It depends on what you try to achieve, if you only need a very simple application, it will do, if you want to learn Android programming, it won't.

Comment: @barotia i agree with you its not a proper way but it is a easy solution.

Comment: The problem with the easy solutions, that if somebody uses to it, when (s)he passes the code the other developer won't understand the most of code.

Comment: I am implementing inapp purchase in my app. In-app purchase buy button is in main activity. And I want to enable the fragment button which is having some extra feature.