# Preserve the state of fragment when previous button is clicked

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

My android application have `BottomNavigationBar`. It contains 5 fragments. One of its fragment contain nested fragment which is mutiple step process.

first nested fragment contain next button.Second nested fragment contain previous and next button.Third nested fragment contain previous and submit button. Each fragment have different `EditText`.

After adding the values in first fragment, when i click next button it goes to second fragment. In second fragment when i click previous button it goes to first fragment again and same process applies to second and third fragment

My questions is:

1)When previous button in second fragment is clicked, i want all the values of `EditText` in first fragment as it is and when again next button of first fragment is clicked, i want all the values of `EditText` in second fragment as it is. Is there any way to do this?

2)I want all the `EditText` values of all nested fragments when user clicked on submit button in third fragment.How to do that?

Comment: Which fragment contains `EditText`  and in which fragment you want to use it's value?

Comment: All the fragments contains EditText. I want all the values in the last fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution of my first question.

I have used `popBackStack()` method of `FragmentManager`. Using this i can go back to the previous fragment of stack.I have added this code in `OnClickListener` of previous button

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
if(fm.getBackStackEntryCount()!=0){
fm.popBackStack();
}
```

Solution of my second question:

use method setArguments() to set the values and getArguments() to get the values

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

This can be achieved using two ways,

1) Fragment savedInstanceState

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17135346/7316675

2) Keep you values stored at some activity or application level, and access it on resume of fragment screen

Comment: I tried all solutions given in the link but nothing happened.

Comment: https://medium.com/@bherbst/saving-fragment-state-yourself-522c3bca78c7

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Bundle` to store the values and then restore them when you restore the fragment. You could either do this in `onStop()` (recommended) or `onPause()`.

```
Private static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "ADDRESS" ;
@Override
Public void onstop(){
   Bundles state = new Bundle ();
   String  address = etv1.getText().toString();
   // Get more strings from the etvs
   state.putString(KEY_ADDRESS, address);
   // Store more strings into the bundle
   setInitialSavedState(state)
}
```

To restore the values you use either the saved instance state the system passed to `onCreate()` , or pass the bundle to a self created public bundle in `onCreate()` and access in `onResume()` like so:

```
String address = bundle.getString(KEY_ADDRESS);
```

As for the results being passed you could communicate the bundles to their parent activity whenever the next or previous button is pressed and do with it as you please when submit is pressed. Learn more on How to do that from the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247954/communicating-between-a-fragment-and-an-activity-best-practices/25392549#25392549) on how to do that

Comment: i got the this error:setInitalSavedState in Fragment can not be applied to android.os.Bundle