# Android Studio/Kotlin - findViewById crash my app

Tags: android, function, kotlin, findviewbyid

The program stop when it reach the findViewById and I can't figure out why :

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen)

    handler.postDelayed({ setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) }, 500) // 5 seconds
    val imageView: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.splashScreenIMG)
    Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.sligames_waiting).into(imageView)
}

    fun showButtons()
{
    val view: View = findViewById(R.id.boutonOui)
    val cx = view.width / 2
    val cy = view.height / 2
    val finalRadius = hypot(cx.toDouble(), cy.toDouble()).toFloat()
    val anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(view, cx, cy, 0f, finalRadius)
    // make the view visible and start the animation
    view.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    anim.duration = 1500
    anim.start()
}
```

I execute this function from another file with this line :

```
MainActivity().showButtons()
```

Here's the stack trace :

```
2020-06-01 12:55:02.783 22557-22557/com.example.yourmajesty E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.yourmajesty, PID: 22557
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:163)
    at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:174)
    at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:738)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:692)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:659)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.findViewById(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:479)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:214)
    at com.example.yourmajesty.MainActivity.showButtons(MainActivity.kt:122)
    at com.example.yourmajesty.Dialog.dialogChanger(Dialog.kt:26)
    at com.example.yourmajesty.MainActivity$dialogBoxDiseappear$2.run(MainActivity.kt:190)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7695)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's almost impossible to tell what causes the problem like this.
Edit your question and put your stacktrace

Comment: `MainActivity()` - never instantiate activities by yourself

Comment: @ali73 Here you go

Comment: @a_local_nobody plz  Complete your question.

Comment: @a_local_nobody tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MainActivity().showButtons()
```

You can't initiate an object from your `activity`. You can only launch it and bundle data with its `Intent`

Please refere to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247954/communicating-between-a-fragment-and-an-activity-best-practices) If you're trying to communicate with `MainActvitiy` from a `fragment`

Answer (score 0):

For creating a reference to a class's objects in Kotlin, you can use

`(activity as MainActivity!!)?.showButtons()`

What this will do is it will create a reference of already running class instead of creating one more instance which will always give NPE for Views as it's not instantiated.

Also, remember referencing views of other `Class` or `Fragment` only works when that class has a running instance, you can reference functions which don't actually need to create views and only need the `Context`, but referencing Views or any objects which need to be initialized first give the NPE.