# How to change background color of Tablayout from a fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I have created a tablayout in MainActivity and bunch of fragments using viewpager.
I want to change the color of tablayout when I click a button present in fragment.
So how do I refer to tablayout created in MainActivity so that I can change it's color in respective fragments?

Comment: I'd say create the method to change tab colors in MainActivity. Then create nested interfaces in the fragments and implement these interfaces in MainActivty. Check this link for more info about communication between fragment -> activity. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247954/communicating-between-a-fragment-and-an-activity-best-practices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change background color of tablayout using `addOnTabSelectedListener` of `tablyout` according to position of tabs, like below code:

```
     tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                    switch (tab.getPosition()){
// Change color of tab layout according to tab position
 
                        case 0:
                            tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.teal_200));
                            break;
                        default:
                            tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                            break;
    
                    }
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    
                }
            });
```