# Roboguice Fragement pass data

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, roboguice

I'm using RoboGuice in my Android application, I'm not sure how to pass object between 
Activity to Fragment?

I am aware about an approach where in you can serialize and pass in the bundle. In this article
[How to pass data between fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194548/how-to-pass-data-between-fragments/14572708#14572708) in one of the comments it is mentioned

> *If you use Roboguice you can use the EventManager in Roboguice to pass data around without using the Activity as an interface. This is
>   quite clean IMO.*

I'm not sure how to do that, can anyone give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Since Fragments are contained within an Activity, and you normally have a reference to it, it's pretty common for a Fragment to expose either a specific constructor or setter methods that the Activity can invoke. There's no need for serialization. To got the other way (Fragment -> Activity) the Fragment should expose an interface that the Activity can listen for events on.

Comment: No, it has to work the other around : the fragment has to pull a listener from the interface. Fragments have their own lifecycle and the activity doesn't know about it. An activity can't guarantee to set a listener each time an instance of fragment is created.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that approach is unique to *roboguice*.

I prefer event propagation as opposed to the (perfectly acceptable) callback approach outlined by dmon. I have provided a mini-guide [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/19988354)...I suspect roboguice's version is very similar. 2 components (activity + fragment), fragment broadcasts a 'I did this' message whilst the activity declares 'I'm listening for that'...