# Data Persistence ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am using `ViewPager` to show the multiple views of the form, like name and email on first view and rest on others.

Now the problem is:

- Enter Data on page 1 navigate to page 2 and then to page 3.
- come back to page 1 the data is not there.

I have a save button on the last page so I also need a way to retrieve the data from other pages there.

If I can get a way I can save the data on page 1 when it is changed to page 2 like `onDestroy` method on activity.

Is `ViewPager` inappropriate for my purpose here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `ViewPager` is fine for this purpose. All you need to do is to save data entered in first and second fragments to your parent `Activity` and fetch it when you hit `Save` in your last fragment.

EDIT: Check [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194548/how-to-pass-data-between-fragments) and [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343241/passing-data-between-a-fragment-and-its-container-activity) related SO questions

Comment: I am using the V4 support library here so how can I save data to the parent activity as the user swipes between views

Comment: This doesn't explain persistence between page swipes at all?

Comment: @G_V Yes it is not, but this problem was solved. Plus it's a bit obvious - fragments are destroyed when they off the offscreen limit, so by default ViewPager are not persistent.

Comment: I don't think we're using the same definition of persistence here.

Answer (score 3):

I have implemented something similar in my GitHub project: [View Pager Form](https://github.com/ashwindmk/Android-View-Pager-Form)