# Android tabbed activity losses data when slide

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I created tabbed activity using view pager with three fragments (f1,f2,f3), if I made changes to f1 then when I slide f2 get back out won't lose the data but when I slide to f3 the changes on f1 were lost ,I want all the data to persist while sliding, how to do that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data Persistence ViewPager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660441/data-persistence-viewpager)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change Offset Page Limit of your viewPager like below.

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

This method:

> Sets the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the
>   current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html