# How to update my fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle

I'm passing data from fragment to another fragment with a bundle, but I have a map and I want to update this fragment and non replace it...this is the code in the MainActivity:

```
Mapped map = new Mapped();
    final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("Position",one);
    bundle.putString("ID",two);
    map.setArguments(bundle);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mapView, map).commit();
```

and every time it delete the old fragment...How can I do to update it and not replace?

EDIT: this is the code of MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements Connection.SendMessage
{
ViewPager Tab;
TabPagerAdapter TabAdapter;
ActionBar actionBar;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TabAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    Tab = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    Tab.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener()
    {
     public void onPageSelected(int position)
     {
       actionBar = getActionBar();
       actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
     }
     });

    Tab.setAdapter(TabAdapter);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener()
    {
        public void onTabReselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,FragmentTransaction ft)
        {
        }
        public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
        {
         Tab.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }
        public void onTabUnselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,FragmentTransaction ft)
        {
        }};
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Connessione").setTabListener(tabListener));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Mappa").setTabListener(tabListener));

}


public void send(String one, String two)
{
    Mapped map = new Mapped();
    final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("Position",one);
    bundle.putString("ID",two);
    map.setArguments(bundle);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mapView, map).commit();

}
}
```

Comment: Which fragment you want to refresh? `Mapped`?

Comment: Yes, Mapped fragment

Comment: Ok I am writing you a simple way to do

Comment: Thanks, I've used interface and bundle to do it...

Comment: So you have solved issue?

Comment: No, I have the same problem :(

Comment: I just write one solution, hope it work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The communication between fragments must be done through the parent FragmentActivity like documentation says:

> Often you will want one Fragment to communicate with another, for example to change the content based on a user event. All Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly.

The problem is how to refresh something in the ui. If you call replace to make the back navigation, in the OnCreateView of the new fragment you get the value of the parent activity. If you use the popbackstack to navigate backwards you should implement an interface.if you show the two fragments together, only use the fragment activity to refresh data.You can chage this:

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mapView, map).commit();
```

for this:

```
MyFragment myFragment = (MyFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.test_fragment);
if(myFragment!=null){
    myFragment.update();
}
```

I'll give you some links to talk about this:

- http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9977370/944630
- [How to pass data between fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194548/how-to-pass-data-between-fragments)

hope you help

Comment: I've tried to this method, but it gives me some errors: I searched the id of the fragment, but when I try this:
Mapped map = (Mapped)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapView); 
I see this error: inconvertible types, cannot cast 'android.app.Fragment' to 'com.example.mypc.tips.Mapped'...why?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

this is xml file...

Comment: With google maps v2 you should use MapFragment instead Mapview, something like this:                                                                                        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

Comment: Here you can see how to do it:  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map

Comment: You should follow the documentation, you're  implementing this  fragment badly

Comment: so I need to delete mapView and put fragment?

Comment: Usually each tab show one fragment. Your Mapped.java should extend from Fragment (or supportfragment, mapfragment or whatever) and inflate a layout.xml. Inside this layout.xml should be defined a Fragment  with this code:`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <fragment xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" android:id="@+id/map" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"/>` and then you can call findfragmentbyid from activity

Answer (score 0):

You could try this solution:

1. add `Mapped` with a tag `myMap`:

   ```
   Mapped map = new Mapped();
   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.mapView, map, "myMap").commit();
   ```
2. make a method in `Mapped`, named `addData(Bundle data)`, then you can pass data by this method when you need.
3. after data added to `Mapped`, then refresh it by:

   Fragment mapFrg = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("myMap"); 
   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(mapFrg);
   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().atach(mapFrg).commit();
4. in `Mappde`, in `onCreateView()`, each time check `MapView` is null or not

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks..it will be great! But now I'm thinking to use a second broadcast receiver in this fragment, so I receive data directly

Comment: oho, so my answer will be no use

Comment: Can't understand why you said `I have the same problem` three hours ago, otherwise I would not take much time to write it