# Passing data between fragments contained in an activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity A with 3 fragments. Each fragments replaces each other, hence at a given time only 1 is visible.

HomeFragment has 2 textviews wrapped inside 2 cardviews. Each cardview represents a text value which comes from Fragment1 and Fragment2. When I click on say Card1,I get to the Fragment1.

Fragment1 has some cardviews, when I selects any of them I navigate back to HomeFragment and update the cardview text based on my selection in Fragment1.Here is the switch statement, depending upon what card user selects I put that in a bundle and pass it to HomeFragment.

```
 switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.card_view0:

            Fragment1Bundle.putString("Test", "Testing");
            bundle.putBundle("Fragment1Bundle", Fragment1Bundle);
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slideup, R.anim.slidedown, R.anim.slideup, R.anim.slidedown);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            break;
```

Fragment2 has same behavior as Fragment 1.

```
switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.card_view0:

            Fragment2Bundle.putString("Test2", "Tetsing");
            bundle.putBundle("Fragment2Bundle", Fragment2Bundle);
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slideup, R.anim.slidedown, R.anim.slideup, R.anim.slidedown);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            break;
```

My challenge is that I am using bundles to pass data between fragments, My home fragment gets updated with the data it from fragment1 but when I go to fragment 2 and after making the selection come back to Home fragment, my fragment1 data is set to default. This is what I am doing in Home Fragments onCreateView()

```
  try {
          bundle1 = getArguments().getBundle("Fragment1Bundle");
          bundle2 = getArguments().getBundle("Fragment2Bundle");


          tv.setText(bundle1.getString("Test") == null ? null : bundle1.getString("Test"));

            tv2.setText(bundle2.getString("Test2") == null ? nul : bundle2.getString("Test2"));

   } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.printStackTrace());
    }
```

I know that I am creating a new Homefragment in my fragment transaction in both fragment1 and fragment2, How can I keep just 1 instance of Home fragment around.

Comment: Think I would simply create a separate singleton class holding the shared values, then fragment1 writes by doing something like `TextHolder.getInstance().setTest1("Test1")`, similar for fragment2 `TextHolder.getInstance().setTest2("Test2")`. Finally in `onResume` of your home fragment read the values by `TextHolder.getInstance().getTest1()` and `TextHolder.getInstance().getTest2()`. Alternatively you could use something like EventBus to keep a common object but the result would ultimately be about the same.

Comment: @Noble6, How is your progress so far? I will be doing something similar to  your issue.

Comment: @TheOriginalAndroid, I am using a singleton model class and reading and writing data to it for now. Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: @Noble6, I can understand how your technique of using singleton static (I assume) works, good for you!  However there may be an issue when user hit Home key or switch to another app (without hitting the Back key).

Answer (score 1):

Another design recommended by Google is to use the main **Activity and 2 fragments** (in your case Fragment1 and Fragment2). I can see your problem of passing data bundle to HomeFragment. This suggested design uses `MainActivity` which is declared static (may be required for scoping issue). And it uses an **interface** to be established between Activity and a Fragment. I think the interface is easier than passing bundle back to the HomeFragment.

A Google webpage is @ [Communicating with Other Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html). This is not just my opinion. A good SO link, I think, is [How to pass data between fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194548/how-to-pass-data-between-fragments).

Code snippet from the webpage...

An example of Fragment to Activity communication:

```
public class HeadlinesFragment extends ListFragment {
   OnHeadlineSelectedListener mCallback;

   // Container Activity must implement this interface
   public interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
       public void onArticleSelected(int position);
   }
...
```

An example of Activity to Fragment communication:

```
public static class MainActivity extends Activity
        implements HeadlinesFragment.OnHeadlineSelectedListener{
    ...

    public void onArticleSelected(int position) {
        // The user selected the headline of an article from the HeadlinesFragment
        // Do something here to display that article
    }
}
```

Note:

- `OnHeadlineSelectedListener` is the interface created by the Fragment.
- The created method onArticleSelected has a parameter `position`, which comes from the **ListView** in ListFragment (in the sample).
- You can still set data bundles and send data between Activity and Fragment. However I have not sent back data from Fragment to Activity. I normally use Fragment to handle much of UI updates.

Answer (score 0):

how to pass values from activity to already open fragment and update array-list help me please. when I using interface the array-list size is zero what I do? do not us bundle method.

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity{

```
String desc = "data";
OnDataPassedListener onDataPassedListener;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    String passedArg = getIntent().getExtras().getString("id");
    Log.d("data",passedArg);
    Scription scription = new Scription();
    onDataPassedListener = (OnDataPassedListener)scription;
    onDataPassedListener.onDataPassed(passedArg,desc);

}
public interface OnDataPassedListener {
    void onDataPassed(String text,String name);
}
```

}

```
public class Test extends Fragment implements
```

Main2Activity.OnDataPassedListener{

.
.
.
.
@Override

```
public void onDataPassed(String text,String name) {
    monthlylists.get(Integer.valueOf(text)).setFood_type(name);
}
```