# What callback exists for a FragmentActivity, ie. onAllFragmentsHaveBeenCreated()?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am trying to find a callback for my FragmentActivity that happens 'after' all of the fragments have called 'onCreateView'.

The reason for this is that my Fragment implement my interface:

```
public interface LifeCycleFragment {
    public void onResumeFragment();
}
```

and when i call the fragment from MyActivity:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity
  onCreate() 
    fragment.onResumeFragment()
```

getActivity() ends up being null:

```
class MyFragment extends Fragment implements LifeCycleFragment

@Override
public void onResumeFragment() {
    Log.e(TAG, "- ON RESUME -");

    FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
    // *****ACTIVITY IS NULL HERE AND THAT'S A PROBLEM ***//
```

I am not sure how to tackle this problem and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place `getActivity`() in override `onActivityCreated` method, and save it in the class for `onResumeFragment`(). I hope the Activity is still kept the same during onPause().

Answer (score 0):

Would you like sample code to communicate between Fragment and Activity? I posted an answer in SO about it @ [Passing data between fragments contained in an activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308970/passing-data-between-fragments-contained-in-an-activity/29326785#29326785).  The respective Google webpage is @ [Communicating with Other Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).

Good luck and have fun...