# How can I pass two values to another fragment?

Tags: android, android-intent

How can I pass two values to another fragment. I am passing one parameter (`log`). Now I want to add another parameter "`id`".

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), ViewMyCommande.class);
        HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        String tid = map.get("log").toString();
        intent.putExtra("log", tid);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

I am retrieving its value like this:

```
String log = getArguments().getString("log");
```

Comment: Simply put another extra! `intent.putExtra("log2", position);` and retrieve it with `int position = getArguments().getInt("log2);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass data between fragments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194548/how-to-pass-data-between-fragments)

Comment: in u r code u are starting new Activity you want to pass data to fragment or  activity

Comment: You can use all the putExtra that you want!

Answer (score 2):

U can send one more parameter in a similar way you are sending/retrieving the first parameter

```
intent.putExtra("keyName", "somevalue");
getStringExtra(String keyName)
```

or you can compose an object with all the values and send along with the intent.

```
i.putExtra((Parcelable) myParcelableObject);
or
i.putExtra((Serializable) myParcelableObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

are we talking about fragments or activities??

if you wanna pass data to other activities you must use intent like you and use

```
intent.putExtra("key", data);
```

for each data that you will pass

and if you wanna pass data to fragment you can use new instance in you fragment class

```
public static MyFragment newInstance() {

    Bundle args = new Bundle();

    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    args.putParcelable("key",data);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

you must declare your object like as parcelable

i hope that this will help you

Answer (score 0):

create a variable in fragment main activity 
 like

```
String message;
```

suppose message value is "frag";
and use it from any fragment of this activity
like

```
if(fragment_main_activity_name.message.equals("frag"))
    {

    }
```

enjoy happy coding :) please make it as right if its helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), ViewMyCommande.class);
    HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    String key = "log";
    intent.putExtra("key", key);
    intent.putExtra("value", map.get(key))
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

PS: In your code you have a line like this `String tid = map.get("log").toString();` as your map is already a `<String, String>` map, there is no need to call `Object::toString` in it. Just call `String tid = map.get("log")` that will get you a *String*.

Another suggestion is to set this *key*  `"log"` that you are using as a constant, than accessing it from the bought Activities. You would add a field like this into your *Activity class*  `private static final String MAP_KEY = "log";` than you could use it in you code, so in the code above, you could remove the `String key = "log";` line and replace `key` by your constant, so the two intent lines would look like this:

```
intent.putExtra("key", MAP_KEY);
intent.putExtra("value", map.get(MAP_KEY))
```

Another suggestion is to extract the bouth keys that you're using in putExtras as public constants, then use these in the Activity that you are receiving the data. Something like this:

```
public static String KEY = "key";
public static String VALUE = "value";
```

Then use it in the intent lines.

```
intent.putExtra(KEY, MAP_KEY);
intent.putExtra(VALUE, map.get(MAP_KEY))
```

When in you *SecondActivity*  you can get these values as `getArguments().getString(FirstActivity.KEY);` same for value.

Another observation, if your key will be constant you don't really need to send the key to your *SecondActivity*.

If you need all these map in your *SecondActivity*  you could call `putExtra` and place you map in it. Then in *SecondActivity* you would need yo call `HashMap<String, String> firstActivityMap = (HashMap<String, String>) getSerializable(MAP)`

*OBS: maybe it's a bit confusing, I hope community could help to improve this answer*