# Fragment communication - Fragment to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need help on understanding how the following scenario works and how to achieve the result.

I have a class called `ShoppingCart`. 
It has a method called `addItemsToShoppingCartFromPreviousOrder`.
Now I have a fragment called `PreviousOrderFragment` with `onCreateView` method which is using the `RecyclerView`. Its a list of previous orders. 
I have multiple lists. Now I want to know how to call the `addItemsToShoppingCartFromPreviousOrder` method from `ShoppingCart` into my fragment.
so that when the user clicks a list, it will add to the cart.

Comment: If you do want to save your time, use EventBus instead https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: The method called `addItemsToShoppingCartFromPreviousOrder` does the job. I have to know how to call or where to call that method. For example, on my fragment `onCreateView` I added the `onClickListner` won't do nothing. And I cannot use the third party library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass data between fragments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38452210/pass-data-between-fragments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need do that:

In you Adapter of RecycleView put:

```
  private ItemListener mListener;
  ...
  public void setmListener(ItemListener mListener) {
     this.mListener = mListener;
  }
  ...
  public interface ItemListener {
     void onItemSelected(Item item);
  }
```

Item = The item selected

them...
In your ViewHolder of Adapter put that:

```
 public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public TextView tv_id;
        public TextView tv_url;
        public TextView tv_login;

        public Holder (View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tv_id = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_id);
            tv_url = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_url);
            tv_login = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_login);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                Integer position = Integer.valueOf(getLayoutPosition());
                mListener.onUserSelected(mList.get(position));
            }
        }
    }
```

OBS: That ViewHolder is a InnerClass of Adapter

Them all you need do is:

In your fragment

```
mRecycleViewAdapter.setmListener(this)
```

Them make your fragment:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements MyRecycleViewAdapter.ItemListener
```

And override :

```
 @Override
    public void onItemSelected(Item item) {
        //call addItemsToShoppingCartFromPreviousOrder 
    }
```

[Here](https://github.com/hlandim/GitUserSearch) is a example,
see [SearchFragment.java](https://github.com/hlandim/GitUserSearch/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/hlandim/gituserssearch/fragment/SearchFragment.java) and [UsersListAdapter.java](https://github.com/hlandim/GitUserSearch/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/hlandim/gituserssearch/adapter/UsersListAdapter.java)

Answer (score 0):

1- Create a interface call it for ex. OnItemClicked

```
Interface OnItemClick{
    void onItemClicked(/*pass your selected object*/);
}
```

2- make the fragment implement this interface

```
Class PreviousOrderFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemClicked{
 void onItemClicked(/*pass your selected object*/){
        /** here you have the select object when item clicked from the activity **/
         addItemsToShoppingCartFromPreviousOrder(); 
 }
}
```

3- Take an instance from the fragment in the Activity

```
Class YOUR_Activity extends Activity {
  PreviousOrderFragment fragment = new PreviousOrderFragment ();
  /// in the onClick event 
  public onClick(View v){
    fragment.onItemClicked(/**pass the selected object*/);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

see [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38452210/pass-data-between-fragments/38452654#38452654), Already explained all the possible ways to make communication between fragments.

But a good way is to use **[EventBus](https://github.com/reverseBits/EventBus)** when you have complicated communication between Many Activities and Fragments, It's much easy and fast,and a better approach then any of this described in above linked answer.