# Android Studio - data moving within tabs/fragments

Tags: android-layout, listview, android-studio, android-fragments

I am currently doing on a project that requires me to move my data between tabs/fragments.. Let's say the user clicks on the listView item, they will move to another tab, instead of staying in the same tab. May I know how can I achieve that? Can someone help to solve my query? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can trasnfer data between tabs by set and get Arguments,
Here is Example

```
FragmentTwo fragmentTwo = new FragmentTwo();

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("key1", "data1");
bundle.putString("key2", "data2");
bundle.putString("key3", "data3");
fragmentTwo.setArguments(bundle);

FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, fragmentTwo);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways to do this

1) **Use Interfaces** -use interface to pass data objects. Meshy solution

[**Read more**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194548/how-to-pass-data-between-fragments)

```
public interface onDataCHange{ 
    public void updateData(String data);
}
```

2) **Use Activity Class** - Store model object in activity class and set and get using activity Instance. Quick and Dirty solution

**[Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343241/passing-data-between-a-fragment-and-its-container-activity)**

```
  //Get
  Object dataModel =  (ContainerActivity) getActivity()).getData();

   //Set
   ((ContainerActivity) getActivity()).setData(dataModel );
```

3) **Clean architecture** - Center repository hold model objects. View update model via Singleton Center repository object. Single copy of data flow between throughout the App.

[**Read more**](https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture)

```
@Singleton 
public class UserDataRepository implements UserRepository { 

  private final UserDataStoreFactory userDataStoreFactory;
  private final UserEntityDataMapper userEntityDataMapper;

  /** 
   * Constructs a {@link UserRepository}. 
   * 
   * @param dataStoreFactory A factory to construct different data source implementations. 
   * @param userEntityDataMapper {@link UserEntityDataMapper}. 
   */ 
  @Inject 
  UserDataRepository(UserDataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory,
      UserEntityDataMapper userEntityDataMapper) {
    this.userDataStoreFactory = dataStoreFactory;
    this.userEntityDataMapper = userEntityDataMapper;
  } 

  @Override public Observable<List<User>> users() {
    //we always get all users from the cloud 
    final UserDataStore userDataStore = this.userDataStoreFactory.createCloudDataStore();
    return userDataStore.userEntityList().map(this.userEntityDataMapper::transform);
  } 

  @Override public Observable<User> user(int userId) {
    final UserDataStore userDataStore = this.userDataStoreFactory.create(userId);
    return userDataStore.userEntityDetails(userId).map(this.userEntityDataMapper::transform);
  } 
}
```