# Communication between fragments that belong to two different activities

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm very new to Android development.

I've made some researches to achieve passing data from Fragment A in Activity A to Fragment B in Activity B. 
Is that possible?

All I could get from the tutorials on the internet is that we have to create an Interface that will be implemented by the parent Activity of two sibling fragments. How to achieve it when the fragments belong to two different activities? I'm stuck.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44008851/6950238) answer.

Answer (score 0):

You would achieve it by implementing the said Interface and put the extras into the `Intent` for the `Activity` that has the other `Fragment`.

Pseudo code could look like this

`Fragment A` - calls interface methods on `Activity A` and passes data

`Activity A` - calls `startActivity` with the extras inside the `Intent`

`Activity B` - got started and evaluates the said `Intent` and passes it to  `Fragment B`

`Fragment B` - receives the extras from `Activity B`

Answer (score 0):

you can use Intent to pass data between activity and from sibling fragment call method of activity like `((MainActivity).getActivity).methodSentData(String exampledata)` and `((MainActivity).getActivity).methodGetData();` to get data in the fragment.

methodSentData implements `intent.putExtra("data",data);` to sent data to other activity and methodGetData() implements `getintent().GetStringExtras("data");`

You can use local broadcast receiver.