# How to pass data between nested fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to pass data between nested fragments in the following way:

From stored data in one class, I have loaded data into viewPager fragment **(Fragment #1)**, displayed as such:
[Fragment#1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2QCl.png)

Now when the **Btn** is clicked, another fragment (**Fragment#2**), should launch with data that corresponds with **Fragment#1**, displayed as such:
[Fragment#2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6KTA.png)
The data for **Fragment#2** is coming from **Fragment#1**, which is receiving the data from the class which has the stored data. Suppose there are multiple, **Fragment#1** components in the same viewPager that have the **Btn** and when clicked would have to show **Fragment#2** with data that are specific to each of the **Fragment#1** components. What would be the best approach at trying to tackle this?

I have tried a similar approach, where instead of nested fragments, a fullscreendialog similar to [Fragment#2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6KTA.png) would appear. But that approach was futile since the dialogs could not properly keep track of the fragment position.

Comment: I get the point.. but your illustration is poor. All you're trying to do is to pass data from one fragment to another, we don't need all of these stories. They belabor the point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass data between fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194548/how-to-pass-data-between-fragments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1:**

Implement interfaces (this is the official way to communicate): https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating

**Option 2:**

[EvenBus library](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) (easier but be careful)