# How can I pass data between Fragments?

Tags: java, android

how to pass data from listView in Fragment with customAdapter to map of googleMaps in second Fragment to addMarker() Function?
this is my classes are important:

FragmentOne(the listView):

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

private static ArrayList<MapModel> mMapList;
private static MapCustomAdapterSearch mAdapter;
private static ListView mListView;
private MapDBHelper mMapDBHelper;
private GetMapsAsyncTaskInternet mGetMapsAsyncTaskInternet;
private static ProgressDialog mProgressDialogInternet;
private static FragmentOne mFragmentOne;
private View mView;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one_layout, container, false);

    mListView = mView.findViewById(R.id.list);

    mFragmentOne = this;

    mMapDBHelper = new MapDBHelper(getActivity());
    mMapList = mMapDBHelper.getAllMaps();
    mAdapter = new MapCustomAdapterSearch(getActivity(), mMapList);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    registerForContextMenu(mListView);

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intentSearchToAddInternet = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), FragmentTwo.class);
            intentSearchToAddInternet.putExtra(getString(R.string.movie_edit), mMapList.get(position));
            getActivity().startActivity(intentSearchToAddInternet);
        }
    });
    return mView;
}


// Set movies in FragmentOne
public static void setMaps(ArrayList<MapModel> list) {
    mMapList = list;
    mAdapter.clear();
    mAdapter.addAll(list);
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

// Sets off the menu of activity_menu
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_menu, menu);

    // SearchView of FragmentOne
    final MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

    // Change colors of the searchView upper panel
    menuItem.setOnActionExpandListener(new MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            // Set styles for expanded state here
            if (((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar() != null) {
                ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.DKGRAY));
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
            // Set styles for collapsed state here
            if (((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar() != null) {
                ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    // Continued of SearchView of FragmentOne
    final android.support.v7.widget.SearchView searchView = (android.support.v7.widget.SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();
    if (searchView != null) {
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo((getActivity()).getComponentName()));
        searchView.setQueryHint(Html.fromHtml("<font color = #FFEA54>" + getResources().getString(R.string.hint) + "</font>"));
        searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                // Search movies from that URL and put them in the SQLiteHelper
                String urlQuery = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=31.73072,34.99293&radius=1000000&rankby=prominence&types=food|restaurant&keyword="
                        + query +
                        "&key=API_KEY";
                mGetMapsAsyncTaskInternet = new GetMapsAsyncTaskInternet();
                mGetMapsAsyncTaskInternet.execute(urlQuery);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}

// Sets off the menu of list_menu
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list_menu, menu);
}

// Options in the activity_menu
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

// Options in the list_menu
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    int listPosition = info.position;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.addMap:  // Edit the movies on MainActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AddMapMe.class);
            intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.map_add_from_internet), mMapList.get(listPosition));
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}

// stopShowingProgressBar
public static void stopShowingProgressBar() {
    if (mProgressDialogInternet != null) {
        mProgressDialogInternet.dismiss();
        mProgressDialogInternet = null;
    }
}

// startShowingProgressBar
public static void startShowingProgressBar() {
    mProgressDialogInternet = ProgressDialog.show(mFragmentOne.getActivity(), "Loading...",
            "Please wait...", true);
    mProgressDialogInternet.show();
}
```

FragmentTwo(of Map):

```
public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
private MapView mMapView;
private View mView;
private MapModel mapModel;
TextView textView;
TextView textView1;

final MapModel item = (MapModel) getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable(getString(R.string.movie_edit));

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two_layout, container, false);
    return mView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    mMapView = view.findViewById(R.id.map);
    if (mMapView != null) {
        mMapView.onCreate(null);
        mMapView.onResume();
        mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    MapsInitializer.initialize(getContext());
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    addMarker();
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}

public void addMarker() {
    textView.setText(String.valueOf(item.getLat()));
    textView1.setText(String.valueOf(item.getLng()));
    String lat = textView.getText().toString();
    String lng = textView1.getText().toString();
    double lat1 = Double.parseDouble(lat);
    double lng1 = Double.parseDouble(lng);
    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat1, lng1)).title("Elior home");
    mGoogleMap.addMarker(marker);
    mGoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

MapModel:

```
public class MapModel implements Serializable {

private float lat;
private float lng;
private String vicinity;
private String name;
private String id;
private String icon;
private Geometry geometry;

public MapModel(String name, String vicinity, float lat, float lng, String icon) {
    this.vicinity = vicinity;
    this.name = name;
    this.lat = lat;
    this.lng = lng;
    this.icon = icon;
}


public float getLng() {
    return geometry.getLocation().getLng();
}

public void setLng(float lng) {
    this.geometry.getLocation().setLng(lng);
}

public String getIcon() {
    return icon;
}

public void setIcon(String icon) {
    this.icon = icon;
}

public float getLat() {
    return geometry.getLocation().getLat();
}

public void setLat(float lat) {
    this.geometry.getLocation().setLat(lat);
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getVicinity() {
    return vicinity;
}

public void setVicinity(String formatted_address) {
    this.vicinity = formatted_address;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

MapCustomAdapterSearch:

```
public class MapCustomAdapterSearch extends ArrayAdapter<MapModel> {

private Context mContext;  //Context
private ArrayList<MapModel> mMovieList;  // ArrayList of MovieModel
private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
private MapModel mapModel;

MapCustomAdapterSearch(Context context_, ArrayList<MapModel> movie_) {
    super(context_, 0, movie_);
    mContext = context_;
    mMovieList = movie_;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @NonNull View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    View listItem = convertView;
    if (listItem == null) {
        listItem = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.movie_item_row, parent, false);
    }

    MapModel currentMap = getItem(position);  // Position of items

    // Put the image in image1
    if (currentMap != null) {  // If the position of the items not null
        ImageView image1 = listItem.findViewById(R.id.image1);
        assert currentMap != null;  // If the position of the item not null in the ImageView
        Picasso.get().load(currentMap.getIcon()).into(image1);

        // Put the text in name1
        TextView name1 = listItem.findViewById(R.id.name1);
        name1.setText(String.valueOf(currentMap.getName()));

        // Put the text in address1
        TextView address1 = listItem.findViewById(R.id.address1);
        address1.setText(String.valueOf(currentMap.getVicinity()));

        // Put the text in lat1
        TextView lat1 = listItem.findViewById(R.id.lat1);
        lat1.setText("\n" + "\n" + "Latitude: " + currentMap.getLat());

        // Put the text in la2
        TextView lng1 = listItem.findViewById(R.id.lng1);
        lng1.setText("\n" + "Longitude: " + currentMap.getLng());
    }
    return listItem;
}


private void getLocation() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener((Executor) this, new OnSuccessListener<android.location.Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(final android.location.Location location) {
            // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
            if (location != null) {
                final android.location.Location locationA = new android.location.Location("point A");
                final double latA = mapModel.getLat();
                final double lngA = mapModel.getLng();
                locationA.setLatitude(latA);
                locationA.setLongitude(lngA);

                final android.location.Location locationB = new Location("point B");
                final double latB = location.getLatitude();
                final double lngB = location.getLongitude();
                locationB.setLatitude(latB);
                locationB.setLongitude(lngB);

                float distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass data between fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194548/how-to-pass-data-between-fragments)

Comment: @SHS  I need help with a personal problem