# add new item on list view from two fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working on alarm app , and I am beginner in android development.

In my app I have 3 tabs "edit", "alarm" and "add alarm" .I  have list view in "alarm" tab , and I want in "add alarm" tab add new item in that list , and show it in alarm with old items .

This is my code.

**Alarm class**

```
public class Alarm extends Fragment {

public ArrayList<Times> names = new ArrayList<>();

public Alarm() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
ListView list;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alarm, container, false);;
    list = v.findViewById(R.id.listview);

    //this demo items .
    names.add(new Times( "03:32" , "AM" , "Mon,Wed" , "-Gym Time"));
    names.add(new Times( "07:09" , "AM" , "Wed , Mon" , "-Home Time"));
    names.add(new Times( "12:00" , "AM" , "Tuh" , "-Gym Time"));
    names.add(new Times( "03:36" , "AM" , "Sun,Tue,Wed" , "-Gym Time"));
    names.add(new Times( "05:32" , "AM" , "Wed , Mon" , "-Home Time"));
    names.add(new Times( "03:52" , "AM" , "Mon" , "-Gym Time"));
    names.add(new Times( "08:42" , "AM" , "Sun,Tue,Wed" , "-Gym Time"));
    names.add(new Times( "10:22" , "AM" , "Wed , Mon" , "-Gym Time"));

    myAdapter adapter = new myAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.custom_list_alarm , names);
    Log.e("hi", "onCreateView: " + getContext() );
    list.setAdapter(adapter);



    return v;
}

}
```

and here **myAdapter.java**

```
public class myAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private  Context c;
Fragment fr ;
private int res ;
private ArrayList<Times> time;

public myAdapter() {

}

public myAdapter(Context c , int res , ArrayList<Times> time)
{
    this.c = c;
    this.res = res;
    this.time = time;

}

public  void addAlarm(Times times)
{
    this.time.add(times);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return time.size();
}

@Override
public Times getItem(int position) {
    return time.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if(v == null)
    {
        v = LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(res , null , false);
    }

    TextView tv_name = v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    TextView tv_name2 = v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    TextView tv_name3 = v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    TextView tv_name4 = v.findViewById(R.id.textView4);

    Times t = getItem(position);
    tv_name.setText(t.getTime());
    tv_name3.setText(t.getDay());
    tv_name2.setText(t.getDays());
    tv_name4.setText(t.getSubject());
    return v;
}
}
```

**Add Alarm class**

```
public class Add extends Fragment {


public Add() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

private TimePicker timePicker ;
private TextView tv ;
private Button add ;
private EditText label;
private String format = "";
public String subject = "";


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add, container, false);

    tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    timePicker = (TimePicker) v.findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
    label = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.subject) ;
    add = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.addAlarm);


    Log.e("hi2", "addNewAlarm: " + subject );
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addNewAlarm();
        }
    });




    return v;
}

public void addNewAlarm()
{
    subject = label.getText().toString();
    int hour = timePicker.getHour();
    //int minute = timePicker.getCurrentMinute();
    if (hour == 0) {
        hour += 12;
        format = "AM";
    } else if (hour == 12) {
        format = "PM";
    } else if (hour > 12) {
        hour -= 12;
        format = "PM";
    } else {
        format = "AM";
    }
    Times alarm = new Times(String.valueOf(hour), String.valueOf(format), "Test", String.valueOf(subject));
    myAdapter test = new myAdapter();
    test.addAlarm(alarm);


    //tv.setText(String.valueOf(hour + subject )+ subject ) ;
}

}
```

Comment: Ideally you would want to use a local database here, please do checkout 'Room'

Comment: thank you for your comment , honestly now i just want to add item to an array list , Without storage it for now , so can you help me how pass data from "add" fragment to "alarm" fragment " , many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to do 2 things. The first one is the one you are directly answering, and the second one is the one you have already been suggested (storing them).

For **storing**, if you are doing something really simple, you could do so with SharedPreferences. So you store (alarm_1_time, "00:00) (alarm_1_name, "my name") for each alarm. Check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23024962/9415337). Otherwise you can try more complex methods (maybe 'Room', which I have not tried out, but some fellow user is suggesting).

For **adding to the list view**, you need to:

- Firstly, **pass from one fragment to another one**: as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16036693/9415337). You basically need to do it through an activity.

> Often you will want one Fragment to communicate with another, for
>   example to change the content based on a user event. All
>   Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated
>   Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly.

[Source here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating)

Then, to do so:

**step 1**. Send the data from the new alarm

In *add* fragment:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), YourActivity.class);  // activity that hosts the fragments
intent.putExtra("name", alarm_name);
// you can pass as many as you want (labels, names, times, colours, repeating, active, etc.)
// for example:
// intent.putExtra("time", alarm_time);
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

**step 2**. Receive the data from the new alarm in the activity

In the activity that hosts the fragments:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String my_alarm_name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
```

**Step 3**. now from activity, we send it to the fragment:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("alarm", my_alarm_name);
// do the same for all other info (such as time, repetition, etc.) similarly
// now set Fragmentclass Arguments
Fragmentclass fragobj = new Fragmentclass();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

**Step 4**. receive in fragment in Fragment onCreateView method:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          String strtext=getArguments().getString("message");

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    }
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27626004/9415337) you have an example of this method with all the code. An alternative way is through interfaces, as stated [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html); [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14788738/9415337) you have a question regarding this.

- On second place, **add new element to list view** in the alarms fragment. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4540859/9415337) you have a question with more information regarding this, and [here](https://android--code.blogspot.com/2015/08/android-listview-add-items.html) a post with a more detailed explanation.

  ```
   names.add(new_alarm) // append the new alarm to the list you have
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //notify your custom adapter so that it "refreshes"
  ```