# How to have shared data/object between fragment android kotlin

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

Everytime i am in need of having a shared data to use or to be updated in fragment, i always put the data in activity and create a method to get/update the data then access it in fragment through something like this

```
(activity as HomeActivity).updateData()
```

i feel like this is not the good way to do this, is there any better way to do this? having the same object to be accessed through different fragment

I am a newbie so any advice will be really appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass data between fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194548/how-to-pass-data-between-fragments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following:

1. Create a singleton class
2. In the singleton class create empty or valued variables
3. Create getter/setter for those variables if required
4. Access the variables from other classes/activities using the singleton object of the data holder class

**This a system from MVP/MVC architecture and a very good practice**

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you replace fragment from Activity or from anywhere you can pass data to fragment by setting data as Arguments.

```
   Testfragment = new TestFragment();
   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   bundle.putSerializable("key",<data to pass>);
   fragment.setArguments(bundle);
   replaceFragment(fragment);
```

Access same data in fragment by using

```
      Object obj = getArguments().getSerializable("key")
```