# android share a complex object between activities/fragments?

Tags: android, object, android-fragments

I'm trying to create an android project that works like that:
it has an activity which has two fragments:

1. connects to a remote device
2. use the API of that remote device after it's connected.

so the fragments are:

1. ConnectFragment
2. Usefragment

in the connect fragment I have a method to connect to the remote device with a click on a button:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String ip = ((ConnectableDevice) parent.getItemAtPosition(position)).getIpAddress();
        remoteDeviceController.connect(ip);
        if (remoteDeviceController.isConnected()) {
            listView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Coludn't connect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    }
});
```

once it's connected, I want to move to the other fragment: `UseFragment` (after the line of `listView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`) and I want to pass to that fragment, the object `remoteDeviceController` since it has all the data of the connected device, and it is the one that already connected.

How can I pass the `remoteDeviceController` object? should I create it in the activity so it will maintain it's state when after I switch between fragments? if so, how can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass data between fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194548/how-to-pass-data-between-fragments)

Comment: I don't think so because it is not a UI component, it's a some kind of a controller object, which I want to keep it's state if the user switches between other fragments.

Comment: @Finer could you explain I want to keep it's state?

Comment: @Anchit the `remoteDeviceController ` object has sockets that it opens and receives messages and data from the remote device and it saves it in a queue that I don't want it to get lost.

Comment: @Finer make the queue publically static or try moving the data back and forth using Bundles

Comment: @Finer please follow Ankit's suggestion or you can do it using Service class and that class will interact with all of your fragments and activities.